# Set default JSON format response Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm practicing to make a good RESTful API services following this guide from Google (https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsoncstyleguide.xml) for the json format response.

Is there any way to set the default JSON format for every response because in the guide said

> In order to maintain a consistent interface across APIs, JSON objects
>   should follow the structure outlined below.

```
object {
  string apiVersion?;
  string context?;
  string id?;
  string method?;
  object {
    string id?
  }* params?;
  object {
    string kind?;
    string fields?;
    string etag?;
    string id?;
    string lang?;
    string updated?; # date formatted RFC 3339
    boolean deleted?;
    integer currentItemCount?;
    integer itemsPerPage?;
    integer startIndex?;
    integer totalItems?;
    integer pageIndex?;
    integer totalPages?;
    string pageLinkTemplate /^https?:/ ?;
    object {}* next?;
    string nextLink?;
    object {}* previous?;
    string previousLink?;
    object {}* self?;
    string selfLink?;
    object {}* edit?;
    string editLink?;
    array [
      object {}*;
    ] items?;
  }* data?;
  object {
    integer code?;
    string message?;
    array [
      object {
        string domain?;
        string reason?;
        string message?;
        string location?;
        string locationType?;
        string extendedHelp?;
        string sendReport?;
      }*;
    ] errors?;
  }* error?;
}*;
```

I'm practicing with Laravel 5.4. Should I just make a trait and use make own JSON response format? Because, it's so cumbersome having to write that kind of response every time you return a JSON response.

Comment: Na, I believe Laravel is taking care of that when you are returning your object. You can also specify the output using response()->json([]) for example

Comment: Take a look at http://jsonapi.org/ json api standard. If you choose to use it, there are php based modules supporting it.

Comment: @ayip is it okay to use it in a medium project? because it seems the last update was on 2015. I've read some of the documentation and I would like to use it

Comment: Yes, The json-api specification for 1.0 is released in 2015. The next version of the spec is still in development http://jsonapi.org/format/1.1/

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `Middleware` to intercept the response object and format it as you like, for example I usually use this to append headers in the response:

```
<?php
# app/Http/Middleware/ResponseAPI.php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class ResponseAPI {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        if (in_array($response->status(), [200, 201, 404, 401, 422])) {
            $response->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        }

        return $response;
    }

}
```

--

```
<?php
# app/Http/Kernel.php
.
.
.
protected $routeMiddleware = [
  # others middlewares
  'api.response' => \App\Http\Middleware\ResponseAPI::class
];
```

--

```
<?php
# app/Http/routes.php

$app->group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'middleware' => ['api.response']], function($app) {
    # all routes
});
```

Comment: I think this is a only right decision in that situation. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toJson()` method.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-tojson
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination#converting-results-to-json

Answer (score 0):

You can add middleware to force a JSON response by setting the "accepts" header on the incoming request. Include that middleware in `HttpKernel`'s `$middlewareGroups['api']` to cover all api routes. This is a Laravel ^7.0 solution.

```
<?php
# app/Http/Middleware/JsonResponse.php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class JsonResponse {

    /**
     * Set 'Accept' header to force a JSON response for API routes.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @param  Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {    
        $request->header->set('accept', 'application/json');
        return $response;
    }

}
```

--

```
<?php
# app/Http/Kernel.php
.
.
.
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [...],
    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        ApiJsonResponse::class
    ]
];
```

Credit to Alfredo EM for leading me to this solution.